# Why operations on a large folder is so slow

Tags: linux, system

I have half a million small files in a folder, whose total size is only 70G. I can barely run any commands (e.g. `ls`) without waiting for several minutes, so I decide to group 700 files in a folder, and there are 700 folders. After the grouping, I can run the commands in several seconds.

However, later I try to copy the entire folder using `rsync`, and I find the speed is surprisingly slow (about 8GB/30min, while my harddisk throughput is 150 MB/s or 1GB/7s).

What is making `rsync` (or potentially any other commands) here so slow, and is there a solution?

Comment: noatime can help: http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html